# android studio: source code for code completion for android support library is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, code-completion

android studio: source code for code completion for android support library is missing. For example, code completion:

```
class MyListAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The method argument names should be:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
```

For android support lib: android does not attach them automatically? How to attach them manually?

Android studio: 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the buttons

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>O</kbd>

In the box, select methods

Class full methods

```
public class MyListAdapter implements ListAdapter 
{

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence[] getAutofillOptions() {
    return new CharSequence[0];
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: CRTL+O does show methods with friendly argument names. But ATL+RETURN: implements those methods(not implemented) only, very convenient.